# how to get the number of rows used in a particular column

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I m using getLastRowNum() and getPhysicalNumberOfCells() for the number of used rows and columns respectively but its not giving the correct index of the row.

```
int lastRowNum = sheetAt.getLastRowNum(); 
int lastColNum = sheetAt.getRow(0).getPhysicalNumberOfCells();
```

Any other option to find out the same???

Comment: Have you tried sheetAt.getPhysicalNumberOfRows()?In excel indexing starts at 0 because of which you are not getting the expected result from sheetAt.getLastRowNum()

Comment: Also note that the indexes don't need to be continuous, i.e. you can create row number 0,5 and 8 and still would only have 3 physical rows. Same for Cells.

Comment: the rows are continous. Moreover number of filled rows are 76 but i m getting 112 as output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rows and Cells can be missing, and there is no built in function to return the number of cells used in a column. So you have to write the function yourself.

```
int count = 0;
for (Row row : sheet) {
    if (row.getCell(5) != null) {
        count += 1;
    }
}
```

This retrieves the number of used cells in column F.

Comment: Working fine. Thank you. Just a small addition to it. We need to check whether the cell is blank or no. With this blank cell check its working correct.